# Broken question migration?

Tags: support, migration

This question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/ascii-data-import-how-can-i-match-fortrans-bulk-read-performance-in-c

appears to be migrated to Software Recommendations from StackOverflow.

[image]

It sure doesn't belong at Software Recommendations; it is about writing
C++ code.

When I click on it in the SR recommendations list of questions,
I find myself back at Stackoverflow.  If I attempt
to close it, I get StackOverflow-type close options.

So which is it?

I think this is a broken migration.  I assume a moderator needs to step and do something about it.   In particular, push it clearly back to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As Seth says, it was migrated *to* Stack Overflow:

> [image]

[You can see it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082794/ascii-data-import-how-can-i-match-fortrans-bulk-read-performance-in-c)

You see it in the question list because migrated questions stick around for a month before an automated process deletes them. Clicking on the link automatically redirects for non-mods. You can see the question page on SR by appending `?noredirect=1` to the question URL, like [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16519?noredirect=1).

Comment: "stick around for a couple of hours..." lessee jan 28-22 --> 6 days * 24 ==> 144.  That's "a couple"?

Comment: @IraBaxter edited.

Comment: A couple of hours I would have understood.  A week? (still not "a couple of days" by any standard I know) How many people get to look at a migrated question and be confused by it in that time?  I agree, I'm not the guy that has to do the work :-{ No further response needed.

Comment: Not a couple of days. 30 days. After 30 days, the stub is deleted automatically.

Comment: I guess that 30d limit is also a kind of safety-margin. Though it should not happen (as clearance should happen *before* migration), there are cases where the target site is not a "happy receiver", or a migration was "not proper" for other reasons. In such cases, instead of "migrating back", this gives the option of a "simple Undo" (oops: no pun intended, Undo ;)

Answer (score 2):

The question in question was actually migrated *from* Software Recommendations to Stack Overflow. If you check the original post's [revision history](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/16519/revisions) you can see that Journeyman Geek migrated it over to Stack Overflow on the 22 of January. That's why you get moved over to Stack Overflow when you try to close it ;)

Comment: OK, why does it appear still at SR?  That's not right.

Comment: See Undo's answer below.